# how to send dynamically allocated string using pipe

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, pipe

I have a homework that I need to send bunch of string between processes using pipes.

When I send **string which is created compile time** from child process to main process using pipe , it is sent successfully. Here is what I did at the main and child process.

Child process :

```
    char* str ="from child";
    int lengthOfString=strlen(str)+1;//+1 for null terminator

  write(pipes[0][1],&lengthOfString,sizeof(int));//send the length of string beforehand
  write(pipes[0][1],&str,lengthOfString); //send the actual string
```

Main process :

```
int numberOfChar;
    char* buffer;
    buffer=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
        read(pipes[0][0],&numberOfChar,sizeof(int));//get length of upcoming string
        read(pipes[0][0],&buffer,numberOfChar);//read the actual sting
        printf("received from pipe :%s\n",buffer);
```

However If I try the same thing with the **string which is dynamically allocated**, I receive only NULL as string at the main process. Here is what I did.

Child process:

```
    char* dynamicallyAllocatedString=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str));
    strcpy(dynamicallyAllocatedString,str);
    int lengthOfString=strlen(dynamicallyAllocatedString)+1;//+1 for null terminator

  write(pipes[0][1],&lengthOfString,sizeof(int));//send the length of string beforehand
  write(pipes[0][1],&dynamicallyAllocatedString,lengthOfString); //send the actual string
```

Main process:

```
   read(pipes[0][0],&numberOfChar,sizeof(int));//get length of upcoming string
        buffer=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*numberOfChar);
        read(pipes[0][0],&buffer,numberOfChar);//read the actual sting
        printf("received from pipe :%s\n",buffer);
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
pid_t pid;
int numberOfPipe=1;
int ret;
int c;
int pipeNumber=-1;
int** pipes= (int**)malloc(numberOfPipe*sizeof(int));
 for(c=0;c<numberOfPipe;c++)//create pipe for each process
{
    pipes[c]= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    ret = pipe(pipes[c]);
    if(ret==-1)
        {
            perror("pipe error");
            exit(1);
        }
}


for(c=0;c<numberOfPipe;c++)//create child process
{
pid = fork();
pipeNumber++;
if(0==pid)
{
    break;
}
}
if(0==pid)
{
    // Child process
    int i=0;
    char* str ="from child";
    char* dynamicallyAllocatedString=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str));
    strcpy(dynamicallyAllocatedString,str);
    int lengthOfString=strlen(dynamicallyAllocatedString)+1;//+1 for null terminator
    close(pipes[pipeNumber][0]); //close read side

  write(pipes[pipeNumber][1],&lengthOfString,sizeof(int));//send the length of string beforehand
  write(pipes[pipeNumber][1],&dynamicallyAllocatedString,lengthOfString); //send the actual string

    close(pipes[pipeNumber][1]); //close write side
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    //main process
    printf("main process\n");

    int numberOfChar;
    char* buffer;


    for(c=0;c<numberOfPipe;c++)//close write side of each pipe
    {
        close(pipes[c][1]);
    }

    for(c=0;c<numberOfPipe;c++)//iterate each pipe
    {
        read(pipes[c][0],&numberOfChar,sizeof(int));//get length of upcoming string
        buffer=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*numberOfChar);
        read(pipes[c][0],&buffer,numberOfChar);//read the actual sting
        printf("received from pipe :%s\n",buffer);
    }

    for(c=0;c<numberOfPipe;c++)//close read side of each pipe
    {
        close(pipes[c][0]);
    }
}

printf("end");
return 0;
```

}

what can I do to get the actual string instead of NULL ?
Thanks.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str))` that's not enough to store a C string. If you intended to leave the terminating `'\0'` then be sure to handle the "string" appropriately on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
write(pipes[0][1],&dynamicallyAllocatedString,lengthOfString);
```

You pass a pointer to the pointer to the dynamically allocated string, instead of a pointer to the actual string.

A second problem in your code is that you're not checking the return value from read() or write(). When you're using pipes, you are not guaranteed that your entire requested write or read will succeed.

Both read() and write() can return fewer bytes read or written than what was requested. Your code must check the return value and take the appropriate action. Failure to do so will eventually lead to subtle bugs that will be rather difficult to locate, and debug.

Also, for your "compile time" case, that you claim works correctly, doesn't, for the same reason. Either that's not the actual code you used, or you failed to detect the same bug.